# ssh-copy-id copies key with a wrong comment

Tags: ssh

1. Long ago, on a machine A, I made an RSA SSH key and used the `-C` option to attach a comment to it.
2. Some time after, I didn’t like the comment. I opened the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file and replaced the last column with a new comment.
3. Now I’m setting up authentication to machine B, and I used `ssh-copy-id` to copy my key to this machine.
4. When I open `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on machine B, my RSA key has the old comment in the last column.
5. I grepped through the whole `~/.ssh` and `/etc/ssh` folders on machine A and could not find a single instance of the old comment anywhere.

I’m completely stumped. It’s almost like SSH embedded some sort of a cache somewhere I’m not aware of, which later became stale.

Comment: what is result of `ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -e` (regarding comment part)?

Comment: Were you using an `ssh-agent` at the time? From `man ssh-copy-id` *"Default behaviour without -i, is to check if ‘ssh-add -L’ provides any output, and if so those keys are used. Note that this results in the comment on the key being the filename that was given to ssh-add(1) when the key was loaded into your ssh-agent(1) rather than the comment contained in that file, which is a bit of a shame."*

Comment: Is machine A running MacOS (whose SSH agent has MacOS keyring integration), or does it have some non-OpenSSH `ssh-agent` functionality that will allow you to use password-protected SSH keys without entering the password every time you login to machine A? If you run `ssh-add -l`, does it return anything other than "The agent has no identities" or an error message about failing to connect to the authentication agent?

Comment: @Archemar It says `Comment: "4096-bit RSA, converted by <username>@<hostname> from OpenSSH"` (where <username> and <hostname> are my username and hostname). The last column from `id_rsa.pub` is not used.

Comment: @telcoM BINGO! `ssh-add -l` indeed returns the old comment. Now the only remaining thing is to discover where the hell it is stored. > _does it have some non-OpenSSH ssh-agent functionality_ - yes, I use [`keychain`](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) from Funtoo, but it's just a very thin wrapper on top of vanilla `ssh-agent`.

Comment: I would use `ssh-keygen -c -C "comment" -f id_rsa` option to change comment in **private** key file (and reload ssh-agent)

Comment: @Archemar wow, I had zero idea that the comment is stored in the _private_ key file too (encrypted, I guess? Encrypted with what - my passphrase?) Anyway, please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Archemar the `-c -C` command returns `Comments are only supported for keys stored in the new format (-o)`, which is weird, because if the format is not "new" enough to store a comment, then it should not store an (old) comment. And if it somehow stores the (old) comment, then it would suggest that the format is "new" enough for the `-c -C` option. Anyway, my SSH is getting long in the teeth (7.6p1), so it's time to update I guess (along with all the keys while I'm at it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as from comment.

key comment may be located in

- public key file `id_rsa.pub`
- private key file `id_rsa`
- ssh-agent session `ssh-add -l`

"original" comment is stored in private key file. (I expect this is in case of public key file being deleted)

You can export you private key using

```
ssh-keygen -e [-f input_keyfile] [-m key_format]
```

You may need to play with `-m` option

```
 -m key_format
         Specify a key format for key generation, the -i (import), -e (ex‐
         port) conversion options, and the -p change passphrase operation.
         The latter may be used to convert between OpenSSH private key and
         PEM private key formats.  The supported key formats are:
         “RFC4716” (RFC 4716/SSH2 public or private key), “PKCS8” (PKCS8
         public or private key) or “PEM” (PEM public key).  By default
         OpenSSH will write newly-generated private keys in its own for‐
         mat, but when converting public keys for export the default for‐
         mat is “RFC4716”.  Setting a format of “PEM” when generating or
         updating a supported private key type will cause the key to be
         stored in the legacy PEM private key format.
```

depending on version you can change it using :

```
ssh-keygen -c -C "comment" -f id_rsa
```

exact syntax from `man ssh-keygen` is

```
ssh-keygen -c [-C comment] [-f keyfile] [-P passphrase]
```

if key is changed and ssh-agent is in use, one must re-import it.